# Swap 3 way input switch position

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, smart-switch

Can I change the slave switch in my 3 way circuit to the master/input switch?

I'm trying to wire Wi-Fi switches and it has to be placed at the input box. That box is in a bad location. I'd like to swap them if I can. The slave switch (where I want the master to be) is in a box with another light switch. The other switch is in a box alone.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The nature of 3-way wiring in the walls *forces you* to put the master in a particular location. There's no choice to the matter.  You cannot ascertain that until you open up the boxes and map the circuit.  Sometimes neither location works.

There are at least 5 different ways to wire 3-way switch setups, and there is no standard - in particular, nobody doing 3-way wiring does anything to make it easy for non-electricians to install smart switches. The colors come pretty close to meaning nothing at all.

If you feel the controls at the remote location are inferior, then change to a different type which offers remote switches with the same controls as the master.

Answer (score 0):

No. The un-switched feed comes to wherever it comes. You can't change that without running new wires/cables.

Actually, as long as your 3-way wiring isn't set up as a switch loop (i.e. if the power comes into one box and the load is fed from the other, vs. power and load coming into the same box) you may be able to find a smart switch that can be installed where you want. For example, the Lutron PD6ANS can be installed "load side" (see  [instructions](https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/369831_ENG.pdf)).